# Как задать редактор кода в Unity по умолчанию

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, visual-studio-code

Я открываю C# файл в Unity, но он открывается через блокнот. Сегодня 2020 год, так что ребят, кому вообще нужен блокнот, когда я могу его открыть через Visual Studio Code.

Знаю, можно сейчас залезть в папку проекта и найти там C# файл и открыть там его через Visual Studio Code, но я хочу сразу же c Unity при клике на файл открыть его в Visual Studio Code.

Как задать этот редактор по умолчанию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit -> Preferences -> External tools. И там выбрать нужный редактор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого файлы будут открываться в нём.

Answer (score 1):

Ага, кажется решил проблему. Клик на файл, выбрать из установленных программ для открытия, Visual Studio Code. Теперь Unity открывает этот файл только в этом редакторе.